# Apply dplyr over select number of rows to calculate angular velocity

Tags: r, dplyr

An example of my dataset is structured as follows:

```
dput(head(MovementAnalysis,10))
structure(list(Name = c("Amber", "Amber", "Amber", "Amber", "Amber", 
"Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Jeff"), Sample = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5), X = c(26.66, 26.66, 26.65, 26.64, 26.64, 26.47, 26.46, 26.45, 
26.43, 26.42), Y = c(-12.38, -12.37, -12.36, -12.36, -12.35, -12.23, 
-12.22, -12.22, -12.22, -12.22), .Names = c("Name", "Sample", "X", Y"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I wish to calculate the Angular Velocity for each `Name` using the mathematics of the following, where k = 2.

```
i <- 2
while(i < length(X) - k){
if (i > k)
{
  a <- c(X[i] - X[i-k], Y[i] - Y[i-k])
  b <- c(X[i+k] - X[i], Y[i+k] - Y[i])
  AngularVelocity <- acos(sum(a * b) / (sqrt(sum(a * a)) * sqrt(sum(b * b)))) * (180 / pi)
}

i <- i+1
}
```

I attempted to do this in `dplyr` (as I have attempted below) as my actual dataset has 1 million+ rows, but am stuck on how to leave the first 2 rows (k) and then iterate from row 3 onwards, to calculate Angular Velocity for each `Name`?

```
Output <- MovementAnalysis %>%
  arrange(Name,Sample) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(An = (X - (lag(X)-2) + (Y - (lag(Y)-2))))

Output <- MovementAnalysis %>%
  arrange(Name,Sample) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Bn = (X - (lag(X)+2) + (Y - (lag(Y)+2))))
```

I understand this is a lengthy question, so welcome any feedback on how to improve the question.

**UPDATED**

I had successfully been using code in the answer below for a while now. However, I am now getting an error when trying the code with a new dataset. An example of this dataset is below:

```
# Create list of inviduals, drill number and practical or criterion measure
ID = c("Gus_D1_Practical", "Gus_D1_Criterion", "Hudson_D1_Practical", "Hudson_D1_Criterion")
# Set the seed
set.seed(300)
# Create a data.frame of dummy peak velocity data from two different tracking systems
ExampleDataset <- data.frame(ID = rep((ID), each = 300),
                             Sample = rep(1:300, each = 1),
                              X = runif(300, 4.5, 6.7),
                              Y = runif(300, 4.1, 8))
# Set the SampleRate
SampleRate <- 100
k <- as.integer(SampleRate)
# Calculate Angular Velocity
library(dplyr)
Output <- ExampleDataset %>%
  arrange(ID,Sample) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  do( { a = diff(cbind(.$X, .$Y),lag=2)
  b = tail(a, -k) 
  a = head(a, -k)
  ang_vel = acos(rowSums(a*b)/(sqrt(rowSums(a^2))*sqrt(rowSums(b^2)))) * (180 / pi)
  data_frame(Sample=head(tail(.$Sample,-k),-k), ang_vel) }) %>%
  right_join(ExampleDataset, by = c("ID","Sample"))
```

Unfortunately, when I now try to calculate Angular Velocity the following error is returned:

```
Error in data_frame_(lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 198
```

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a bit different type of application for `dplyr`.  You might try something like

```
 library(dplyr)
  Output <- MovementAnalysis %>%
  arrange(Name,Sample) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  do( { a = diff(cbind(.$X, .$Y),lag=2)
    b = tail(a, -k) 
    a = head(a, -k)
    ang_vel = acos(rowSums(a*b)/(sqrt(rowSums(a^2))*sqrt(rowSums(b^2)))) * (180 / pi)
    data_frame(Sample=head(tail(.$Sample,-k),-k), ang_vel) }) %>%
  right_join(MovementAnalysis, by = c("Name","Sample"))
```

Comment: I have used your code successfully for a while now. However, I am now running into an error that states:                                                                           `Error in data.frame(Name = unique(.$Name), Sample = head(tail(.$Sample,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 431506, 431505
In addition: Warning message:
In acos(rowSums(a * b)/(sqrt(rowSums(a^2)) * sqrt(rowSums(b^2)))) :
  NaNs produced`

Comment: There may be a value of `Name` which is treated differently by `group_by` and `unique`.  Taking another look at your problem and the code, I noticed that `do` will include `Name` in its output so can be dropped in  `data_frame`.   The calculation of `a` is also simplified.  You may still have a problem with the input data which causes the argument of `acos` to lie outside [-1,1] and appears to be generating your `NaNs`.  The answer has been updated with the revised code.

Comment: Hello, I have been using your (revised) code successfully for a while - thanks. However, I am now receiving the following error and unsure how to fix the code? Cheers                                                                                  `Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste0("[", sel, ",]")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`

Comment: I've run the code in my post again and it doesn't throw any errors.  Could you supply a small sample data set which illustrates the problem?

Comment: I suspect it may now be because my sample rate has changed to 100. Even if I define `k = 100` prior, I still receive the error. I shall upload an example dataset.

Comment: Updated with an example dataset.